# Responsive Design problems

Tags: html, css

My first topic here hope I get some valuable answers.

So basically I have been trying to learn more and more about responsive web design and now I have hit a deadend. I'm using the forum software MyBB and I built my own custom theme and used media queries to make it responsive.

It scored a 99/100 on the mobile responsive test on google and it does the job. But I'm not satisfied.

https://gyazo.com/30cb40ba9ce046ec3156311d3b716d81 
As you can see in this image that it is perfectly well but you use the forum on a bigger device, say S6 or Nexus 6S or IPhone 6s plus the content doesn't fit to the screen, Its smaller and I see a lot of whitespace.

I'm using single media query of max-width 700 and that affects all the phones directly.

Any help how to scale down the content according to the screen is appreciated, I know I can make several queries and target the larger devices but if there is any other way around I'll be more than happy to learn.

Some images :-
on IPhone 5s :- https://gyazo.com/2bf46dbe4f316293398d6499e9f113de
on S6 :- https://gyazo.com/9674273d0ac4be9a12db8cece0eca330

I want it just like on 5s.
Cheers :)

Comment: hope this helps you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Have you tried adding a meta viewport tag to your document?

Comment: Yeah code rider I know about that but like I said I don't want to do it that way. Thats my final option. @Sqnkov I have added viewport tag.

Comment: FYI it looks good on my iPhone 6S Plus

Comment: @NickyTheWrench yeah since now I added queries targeting larger screens, Though this isn't my first choice but I couldn't find a way around it.